# Backend Preview Images with vhs 5.1 and TYPO3 9.5.3 crashes

Tags: fluid, typo3-9.x

Now after TYPO3 Update to 9.5.3 Backend Preview calls Exception, when using
`v:content.resource.fal` in Preview Section.

```
<f:section name="Preview">
  <v:content.resources.fal field="settings.falimage" as="images" record="{record}">
    <f:for each="{images}" as="image">
      <f:if condition="{image}">
        <f:image src="{image.id}" treatIdAsReference="1" maxWidth="100"/>
      </f:if>
    </f:for>
  </v:content.resources.fal>
</f:section>
```

Exception in Backend says:

```
Call to a member function exec_SELECTgetRows() on null
```

TYPO3 9.5.3
vhs 5.1
flux 9.1
php 7.2.12

Ticket [#1551](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs/issues/1551)

Do you have any solution or ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old database [$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.0/Breaking-80929-TYPO3_DBMovedToExtension.html?highlight=typo3_db) is removed in TYPO3 9.5. As a quick solution you can install the [typo3db-legacy](https://packagist.org/packages/friendsoftypo3/typo3db-legacy) extension, wich brings back the old database class.

Comment: Okay, should be a solution for now. But i dont know if i actually want to use a legacy EXT :P

Answer (score 1):

With vhs 5.1.1 the Problem is fixed. You dont need typo3db-legacy anymore for this.